# Comparing two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be a set and $X_{i,j}$ subsets of $E$ where $(i,j) \in I \times J $

Compare
$\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcap_{j \in J} X_{i,j}$ and $\bigcap_{j \in J} \bigcup_{i \in I} X_{i,j}$

One thing is clear, if $I=J$ then the two are equal.
We can also distinguish two other sub cases, if $I \subseteq J$ and if $J \subseteq I$, but there is another last subcase which is if $(I \nsubseteq J$ and $J \nsubseteq I)$, which seems impossible for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: Note:  for formatting, you need to surround the coding syntax with dollar signs to get the system to treat it appropriately.

Comment: Take $X_{i,i} = \{e\}$ for $i=j$ and otherwise emptysets. This shows you that those two are different even if $I=J$ (as long as there are at least 2 indexes)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $I \subseteq J$ and $J \subseteq I$ when you write $I \in J$ and $J\in I$?

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson Yes actually, thanks for pointing that out. I'll correct that mistake and consider the question answered by the responder down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $I,J$,
$$\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcap_{j \in J}  X_{i,j} \subseteq \bigcap_{j \in J} \bigcup_{i \in I} X_{i,j}.
$$
In fact,
$$
e \in \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcap_{j \in J}  X_{i,j}
\implies \exists i: e \in \bigcap_{j \in J}  X_{i,j}
\implies \exists i: \forall j,  e \in X_{i,j}\\
\implies \forall j, \exists i: e \in X_{i,j}
\implies \forall j, e \in \bigcup_{i \in I}  X_{i,j}
\implies e \in \bigcap_{j \in J} \bigcup_{i \in I}  X_{i,j}
$$